# A list with correlated countries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables
The first one is similar to:

```
    | id | id_related     | 
    | id1| [id2, id3, id4]|
    | id2| [id1, id4]     |
    | id3| [id1, id2, id5]|
```

The second is similar to:

```
    |id | country |
    |id1| BR      |
    |id2| US      |
    |id3| CO      |
    |id4| IT      |
    |id5| US      |
```

I need a query that return:

```
   | id | id_related     | related_country |
   | id1| [id2, id3, id4]| [US, CO, IT]    |
   | id2| [id1, id4]     | [BR, IT]        |
   | id3| [id1, id2, id5]| [BR, US, US]    |
```

I trying to do a select with a select and concat, but nothing is working. Can someone help me?

Comment: You could try parsing the list of IDs as JSON, resolving them to countries, then GROUP_CONCAT them together.

Comment: i am trying it:
SELECT 
    rt.ids, rt.related_ids, GROUP_CONCAT(country) as countries
FROM 
    related_table as rt
left join 
    all_countries as ac 
ON 
    rt.ids = ac.ids
WHERE
    rt.ids IN (SELECT rt.related_ids FROM rt)

but appears this error: This query ran against the rt database, unless qualified by the query.
however, if do not use group concat it works (returned the countries in different rows)

Comment: Please provide your tables as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Also specify the datatype (string? json?) of desired output columns and exact MySQL version.

Comment: Honestly speaking, using the **SET** data type to simulate an array is not recommended. It's diffcult to manage the contents and maintain the data consistency.  Why not make a foreign key column instead of the **SET** in the first table and have it references the second table?  The FK constraint can warrant the data integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable1(
   id         VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
  ,id_related VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL

);
INSERT INTO mytable1
(id,id_related) VALUES 
('id1','[id2,id3,id4]'),
('id2','[id1,id4]'),
('id3','[id1,id2,id5]');

CREATE TABLE mytable2(
   id      VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
  ,country VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable2(id,country) VALUES 
('id1','BR'),  
('id2','US'),
('id3','CO'),
('id4','IT'),
('id5','US');
```

first of all you should remove `[ ]` characters by using following query

```
SELECT id,
       Trim(BOTH '[' FROM Trim(BOTH ']' FROM id_related)) AS id_related
FROM   table1
```

output result

| id | id_related |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | id2,id3,id4 |
| id2 | id1,id4 |
| id3 | id1,id2,id5 |

then you should use the approach used [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows) to split values to multiple rows

```
SELECT t12.id,
       t2.country
FROM   (SELECT t11.id,
               Substring_index(Substring_index(t11.id_related, ',', numbers.n),
               ',', -1
                      )
               id_related
        FROM   (SELECT 1 n
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 2
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 3
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 4
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 5) numbers
               INNER JOIN (SELECT id,
                                  Trim(BOTH '[' FROM Trim(BOTH ']' FROM
                                                     id_related)) AS
                                                     id_related
                           FROM   table1) t11
                       ON Char_length(t11.id_related) - Char_length(
                          REPLACE(t11.id_related, ','
                          , '')) >=
                          numbers.n - 1) t12
       JOIN table2 t2
         ON t2.id = t12.id_related
```

to get following result

| id | id_related |
| --- | --- |
| id3 | id1 |
| id2 | id1 |
| id1 | id2 |
| id3 | id2 |
| id2 | id4 |
| id1 | id3 |
| id3 | id5 |
| id1 | id4 |

then use `GROUP_CONCAT`,`Concat` and `multiple join` and `Subquery`  to get your desired result  as follows

```
SELECT t12.id,
       t13.id_related,
       Concat('[', Group_concat(t2.country ORDER BY t12.id_related ASC), ']') AS
       related_country
FROM   (SELECT t11.id,
               Substring_index(Substring_index(t11.id_related, ',', numbers.n),
               ',', -1
                      )
               id_related
        FROM   (SELECT 1 n
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 2
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 3
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 4
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 5) numbers
               INNER JOIN (SELECT id,
                                  Trim(BOTH '[' FROM Trim(BOTH ']' FROM
                                                     id_related)) AS
                                                     id_related
                           FROM   table1) t11
                       ON Char_length(t11.id_related) - Char_length(
                          REPLACE(t11.id_related, ','
                          , '')) >=
                          numbers.n - 1) t12
       JOIN table2 t2
         ON t2.id = t12.id_related
       JOIN table1 t13
         ON t13.id = t12.id
GROUP  BY t12.id,
          t13.id_related
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7037d051481d16484da5b16936ad8ece)